# ssrs mail sent but not received

Tags: reporting-services

Using SSRS2012 to send emails. It shows that the email is sent from server but the email address provided doesnt receive anything.

What I have tried so far:

1 - Initially I wanted the email to be sent to 2 email addresses. So I tried just using one but the same result. Says its sent but not received.

2 - On the report configuration, I tried to get the smtp server name by running `get-service smtpsvc` on powershell. But it doesnt show the smtp server name. Where do I check this? Because currently the SMTP server is left blank (if this is why it isnt sending the emails)

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

Found the smtp server. After saving this, and trying to resend the report, it gives the error:

```
Failure sending mail: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROMMail will not be resent.
```

Does no one know how to fix this?

Comment: Please see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189342.aspx for how to setup SMTP for Reporting Service

Answer (score 0):

If you are running reports using subscriptions and sending mails. The following should be configured with a `valid sender address` in your Reporting Services configuration Manager.

[image]

Comment: @Tony i had a look on that website and for SSRS 2014 the setting are the one that p2k just highlighted.

Comment: I put my office365 account email on sender address and smtp.office365.com. And thats when it gives the error i mentioned in the update. Do i have to enable smtp from my account? I cant seem to find an article on that

Comment: I had a look at that page too but its confusing because its still not working. After doing what i did i got the error i mentioned above in my UPDATE